# Create an RTP/RTSP or HTTP stream using OpenCV frames

Tags: c++, opencv, ffmpeg, video-processing, rtp

I have a custom board which takes input stream from a IP camera and the application perform facial detection using OpenCV on the input video stream.

My use case is to provide an output stream through network which will be accessible through VLC on any device connected in the same network.

I tried writing OpenCV frames through VideoWriter:

```
VideoWriter outStream("/home/user/frames/frame.mjpg", CV_FOURCC('M','J','P','G'), CAP_PROP_FPS, img.size(), true);
 if (outStream.isOpened()){
     outStream.write(img);
```

and creating a stream using mjpg_streamer like:

```
mjpg_streamer -i "input_file.so -f /home/user/frames" -o "output_http.so -w /usr/local/www -p 5241"
```

But the above process shows a lot of latency. 
I can't use imshow as my hardware does not have any video output port.

Here is my code : https://pastebin.com/s66xGjAC

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using [imwrite()](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgcodecs/doc/reading_and_writing_images.html#imwrite), to save jpeg images in the directory specified by Mjpeg-Streamer. Write low quality Jpegs, set the " CV_IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY" to the lowest value that satisfies your requirement.